# Unable to install TaillwindCss in Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I installed Vite and now i am trying to install tailwind css for the first time. I followed the doc of tailwind and after running --
**npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer**
I am getting below errors.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-plugin-react@7.25.3
npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.44.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || >=8.0.0" from @eslint-community/eslint-utils@4.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@eslint-community/eslint-utils
npm ERR!     @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.2.0" from eslint@8.44.0
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0-0" from eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.6.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-react-hooks
npm ERR!     dev eslint-plugin-react-hooks@"^4.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (eslint-plugin-react-refresh, the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7" from eslint-plugin-react@7.25.3
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-react
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-react@"^7.25.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7" from eslint-plugin-react@7.25.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-react
npm ERR!     dev eslint-plugin-react@"^7.25.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\avina\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-02T12_58_40_009Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\avina\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-02T12_58_40_009Z-debug-0.log
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: I'd suggest npm cache clean --force and then npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer --legacy-peer-deps. If the issue still persists after following these steps, please provide the contents of the debug log mentioned in the error message (C:\Users\avina\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-02T12_58_40_009Z-debug-0.log)

Comment: i did clear the npm cache and than tried but same error. So i removed ESLINT extension from VSCODE thinking that's causing the issue. Cleared cache again. Than run the same command with --force and it worked. Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: Yeah, ESLint can often cause issues with this and multiple other dependencies so I sort of avoid using it. Glad to hear you've sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

override in package.json and perform audit fix.

```
"overrides": {
    "semver": "~7.5.2"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

At first use this command 'npm install eslint --global'
Then you can use any command which is you need.